# conda when running give RuntimeError: OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load [FIXED]

Tags: python, openssl, anaconda, conda

I was accidentally go to my miniconda directory and `rm -r ca*` (just because I using Arch and when update miniconda3 package, it said there are some certificates were there so it can't perform update, so I removed them)
Now every time I run `conda` command, it give me RuntimeError: `OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load.`

here is the full log:

```bash
$conda env list

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 70, in main_subshell
    p = generate_parser()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 65, in generate_parser
    p = ArgumentParser(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 502, in plugin_manager
    from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/plugins/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/plugins/hookspec.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/plugins/types.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..core.solve import Solver
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .index import _supplement_index_with_system, get_reduced_index
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .subdir_data import SubdirData, make_feature_record
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 53, in <module>
    from ..trust.signature_verification import signature_verification
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/trust/signature_verification.py", line 12, in <module>
    from conda_content_trust.authentication import verify_delegation, verify_root
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_content_trust/authentication.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .common import (
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_content_trust/common.py", line 66, in <module>
    import cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.ed25519
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 61, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 232, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 206, in init_static_locks
    cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 195, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    _legacy_provider_error(cls._legacy_provider_loaded)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 104, in _legacy_provider_error
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load. This is a fatal error by default, but cryptography supports running without legacy algorithms by setting the environment variable CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY. If you did not expect this error, you have likely made a mistake with your OpenSSL configuration.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 129, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 376, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 19, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 75, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 88, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 159, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .subdir_data import SubdirData, make_feature_record
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 53, in <module>
    from ..trust.signature_verification import signature_verification
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/trust/signature_verification.py", line 12, in <module>
    from conda_content_trust.authentication import verify_delegation, verify_root
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_content_trust/authentication.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .common import (
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_content_trust/common.py", line 334, in <module>
    cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.ed25519._Ed25519PrivateKey, # DANGER
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cryptography.hazmat.backends' has no attribute 'openssl'
```

How can I fix this?

---

[edit] p/s:
my problem was fixed as follow:

```bash
export CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY=1
conda install cryptography
```

Comment: It would preferable to file the fix as an answer. Accepting your own answer is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem was fixed as follow:

```bash
export CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY=1
conda install cryptography
```

that's all.